# Dynamic Topic Modelling And NGrams on Mallet

Tags: java, c++, mallet

I am working on a project(master thesis) which requires use of DTMs, and the project is whole built in Java. I have been trying to call the c++ .exe file from my Java code after compiling it on Linux, but it doesn't work. Is there any solution to this implementation issue. Is it related somehow to the OS I  am working on?  (Windows  platform.) Do anyone have any solutions as I already spent a 2 weeks on this problem. :(

Furthermore, regarding the implementation of NGrams Import Data, I have added the pipe TokenSequence2FeatureSequenceWithBigrams() to adapt the sequence for Ngrams. The .mallet file is created as the topics at some point are created, but the topic proportions per document are not generated. When I run it from terminal using -keep-sequence-bigrams it works everything fine. Am I missing any pipe to add ?? Or is there smth else?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion or hints. Its highly appreciated.

Comment: Just a thing that I forgot to mention: I have used the cross compiling from Linux for Windows, and the code still doesnt work on Windows.